# image-url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, sass

**images.js.coffee.erb file:**

```
<%
imgs = {}
Dir.chdir("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/bg/") do
  imgs = Dir["**"].inject({}) {|h,f| h.merge! f => image-url(f)}
end
%>

window.image_path = (name) ->
  <%= imgs.to_json %>[name]
```

**page.js.coffee file:(to get the image path)**

```
icon=image_path("myfile.jpb")
```

**Error:**

```
undefined local variable or method `image' for #<#<Class:0x007ffdaac7cd88> on line 4

4   imgs = Dir["**"].inject({}) {|h,f| h.merge! f => image-url(f)}
```

The problem becomes that my image-url() method does not seem to work.  Why would image_path() work, but image-url not work?

thank you

Comment: Do you mean `image_url` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Because the method **image-url** is not a valid method name for ruby.

Also, its not defined on the rails api documentation, you can check the [api documentation reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) at anytime.

Try to do in your **irb**:

```
def image-url
  puts "Hi"
end
```

and it will say that the code is invalid :)

Comment: image-url seems to work in SASS, which is why I was confused, but either way, I used image_path and it's seems to work ok.  thanks